# Fetch batch of iOS pictures

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, photos, fetching-strategy

I would like to fetch fixed batches of the pictures located on an iOS device. I am using the new [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos), and I already found this workaround:

```
PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];

allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];

// Fetches all photos -> i would like to fetch only some of them
PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:allPhotosOptions];

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(currentIndex, batch_size)];

// Iterates over a subset of the previously fetched photos
[allPhotosResult enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet options:0 usingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    // Do stuff    
}
```

It works fine, but I first fetch all photos with `fetchAssetsWithMediaType` and then select an subset of the result for my app to load, which seems quite heavy...

I wanted to know if there was a way to directly fetch photos batch by batch, and not fetch them all then iterate.
Furthermore, it would be perfect if I could keep the indexes of the last fetched batch, to know where I'll fetch the next batch.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a more detailed search, I finally found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165348/batching-core-data-fetch-results?rq=1) what I was looking for  : 
One just could use   `setFetchBatchSize` from `NSSortDescriptor`.

Comment: NSSortDescriptors doesn't have this fetchBatchSize property. The answer is not clear.